# .NET Core AD authentication

Tags: authentication, active-directory, asp.net-core, authorization

I have a .net core web app that will be on an intranet on most installs, and I really need to authenticate my user

Now, I HAVE figured out how to use JWT with Azure AD, and it works fine, but sometimes, the site won't HAVE Azure, so I'd love to be able to get back either a JWT or some other authentication

Like I said, I do NOT need to expose this to the web, but would love to basically say "Hey, this guy is in our AD, and is in X group" (Yes, I know we are getting into authorization there from authentication

Is there a pure AD middleware out there

Comment: There is no AD authentication or middleware there (i.e. in conjunction with ASP.NET Core Identity for security reasons). But when you intend to host only on Windows, you can use WebListener instead of Kestrel, then the logged in user will be authenticated via NTLM with his credentials (NTLM credentials/token is sent automatically when you visit the page)

Comment: Thanks - Not what I wanted to hear, but good to know

This project is going to roll to 2-3 different kinds of clients:
1)Self Hosted intraweb - and basically we want them to just have to maintain their AD, and nothing else
2)SaaS - and we will deal with it - and use JWT from various providers out there - client gives us a list of who has accounts
3)Client has their own cloud server/AAD/whatever, so we support AAD, other JWT